# Web application not serving with Route53 under wifi?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, amazon-route53, amazon-ebs

I have a node application running in an Ec2 container on port 443. I've added an Elastic IP to the container. When I reference the Elastic IP or IPv4 DNS in the browser, I can see my application. I added a Loadbalancer and attach it with the IP address. When I reference the load balancer in the browser, it also displays my web app as expected. This is where it gets interesting.

When I add a cname beta.hostedzone.com I'm getting mixed results. If I'm on my wifi network the site does not appear. When I use my phone data it does appear. I'm using certificate manager, which routes all 80 traffic to 443 so I'd expect something to appear. Nothing has yet and I'm not sure where to look. I've ruled out a security group issue, any thoughts? I'm stumped. It doesn't happen for every ISP. For example, with spectrum, it's fine. With WOW internet, it fails.

Comment: I'd recommend using an Alias A record instead of the CNAME.  Not sure this is your issue but you'll cut your lookups in half.

Comment: IMHO the problem is more likely to be on your computer or WiFi network as this is all public as far as AWS is concerned. If you edit your question to give details of the IP / domain others can try it.